# Activating conda environment within Python

Tags: python, virtualenv, conda, miniconda

Does conda provide for a way to activate an environment from within a running Python program?

For instance, each virtual environment (`venv`) created with [virtualenv](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/stable/) has a script `venv/bin/activate_this.py` (assuming you are on Linux), that can be used to activate `venv` within a running Python program as follows:

```
activate_this = '/full/path/to/venv/bin/activate_this.py'
with open(activate_this) as file_:
    exec(file_.read(), dict(__file__=activate_this))
```

I am just wondering if I need to adapt virtualenv's `activate_this.py` for this job (virtualenv and conda environments are structured slightly differently, so wouldn't work as is) or there's an existing way.

Comment: @darthbith I was revisiting a Flask web app that worked on a while back. The problem there was that the app itself was running in a virtualenv virtual environment, but there were difficulties installing uwsgi in the same env. So I installed uwsgi module in a separate Conda env. At initialization time the conda env had to be used to start uwsgi but then switch to virtualenv to actually run the app.

Comment: @darthbith so there's a way to switch to a virtualenv environment. See this: https://github.com/pypa/virtualenv/blob/263283be88061b965ead9ebff47c37021d7d3f62/virtualenv_embedded/activate_this.py Was curious if conda has any similar functionality built-in.

Comment: As I said, I don't think there's a way to do this. The reason is probably because conda environments are so much more than virtualenv environments... they can have their own compiliers, run scripts to set environment variables on execution, etc. Why not recreate the virtualenv as a conda env and add uwsgi to it?

Comment: @darthbith you are right about conda envs being more involved. I ended up doing just that - putting everything in a single conda env. I am moving away from virtualenv and just trying to find some parallels between it and conda, thus this question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it is not possible the way you intend to. I am not an expert on this field, but the python interpreter of the virtual environment is different. You can also see that the file will only change things of you system path, so that the python interpreter to use will point to the on of the virtual environment. So I think you actually have to spawn a new python process within your script using the python interpreter of the virtual environment. Like this:

```
import subprocess

subprocess.run(['/full/path/to/venv/bin/python', 'path/to/script.py'])
```

Comment: You are right about this if the other environment uses `python` binary version different than the base env binary. If both envs use same Python version, then the difference between environments is only in the modules that they use which is entirely determined by PATH and can be changed at runtime by using something like `activate_this.py`.